# Formatting date with Swift

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I am trying to Convert a String into Date using Date Formatter .

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd’T’HH:mm:ss’Z’"
var AvailabletoDateTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-07-16’T’08:00:00’Z’")
```

But the AvailabletoDateTime is Returning nil .
Can Someone please Help me ,and let me know if i miss Anything Here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let availabletoDateTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-07-16T08:00:00Z")
```

Answer (score 5):

This looks like you're trying to use an ISO 8601/RFC 3339 date. Usually the date string will *not* include any quotes. It will be: something like `2015-07-16T08:00:00Z`. FYI, the `Z` stands for GMT/UTC timezone (as opposed to your local timezone).

So, in Swift 3:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
let availabletoDateTime = dateFormatter.date(from: "2015-07-16T08:00:00Z")
```

Note, I'm (a) using `ZZZZZ` rather than `Z` in my format string; and (b) explicitly setting the `timeZone`. I do this for my formatter can not only successfully parse the string `2015-07-16T08:00:00Z` into a `Date` object, but that it can also be used to go the other direction, converting a `Date` object into a string in the format like `2015-07-16T08:00:00Z`.

Also note I'm using `'` character, not the `’` character. Nor do I need to set the `calendar`, as `locale` of `en_US_POSIX` is all you need.

For more information, see [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

---

Not, nowadays you'd use the new `ISO8601DateFormatter`:

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let availabletoDateTime = dateFormatter.date(from: "2015-07-16T08:00:00Z")
```

In Swift 3, use this `ISO8601DateFormatter`, if you can, but recognize that it doesn't provide as much control (e.g. prior to iOS 11, you couldn't specify milliseconds). But in this case, it's sufficient.

For Swift 2 rendition, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31691175/3).